# php json response with keys that contain $

Tags: php, json

First, thanks for you reading. Here is my code

data.json

```
{
      "$descriptor": "Testing Json",
      "$url": "NULL",
      "$totalResults": 1499,
      "$startIndex": 1,
      "$itemsPerPage": 1499,
      "$resources": [
        {
          "$url": "NULL",
          "$uuid": "5e7b9312-52e5-4fe1-b3e4-633ca04c9764",
          "$httpStatus": "OK"

        }
    ]
}
```

index.php

```
    <?php

    $file_name = "data.json";

    $file = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_name));

    ?>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Available Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <br>
        <tbody>

        <?php 
LINE 39 ->  foreach($file->$resources as $mydata)
        {
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $mydata->url; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mydata->uuid; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $mydata->httpStatus; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        };
        ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: resources in C:\xampp\htdocs\json-testing\index.php on line 39

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\json-testing\index.php on line 39
```

Just wondering if you could shed some light on this, i'm guessing it's because of the dollar signs in front of the key names. At the moment am manual importing this file were as it will be a query result from a api server.

if it is because of the dollar signs how would i remove them?

Thanks
Anthony,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` is causing the problem (do you need those?) so access like this:

```
$file->{'$resources'}
```

Or if you decode as an associative array:

```
$file = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_name), true);
$file['$resources']
```

But then your `echo` statements will access an array as well:

```
echo $mydata['$url'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been driving me up the wall for hours